Getting Jupyter: command not found even though I used Jupyter before
I recall using jupyter nbconvert successfully before, but now, when I try opening a new terminal window and running jupyter I just get zsh: command not found: jupyter. What gives?

I need to use the venv in which I installed jupyter.
python -m venv ./venv
source ./venv/bin/activate

And then jupyter works.

python -m venv ./venv is entirely unnecessary if you already have a virtual environment dir. But it's kind of obvious that if you have a virtual environment, you need to activate that (that's how venvs work), so if you figured this out basically right after posting your question, then anyone else can reasonably be expected to do the same, and there's no reason for this question to stick around.
